# Play 2.0-RC2 doesn't work on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I created a small app in play 2.0-RC2, but I can't push it to heroku. The error I'm getting is:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      play:sbt-plugin:2.0-RC2 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/tmp/build_lhsutbwdl8uo/project/}default-be7cb3/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#sbt-plugin;2.0-RC2: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?  !     Failed to build app with SBT 0.11.0  
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Scala app
```

I thought heroku just doesn't support play 2.0-RC2, but apparently James Ward succeeded pushing play 2.0-RC2 app to heroku :/ (http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku)

Comment: Does your `project/plugins.sbt` file have the Typesafe repo in it?  Like: https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars-scala/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt

Comment: I just noticed that RC3 is out and it appears that they did something that might have changed RC2 (possibly broken it).  I'm trying RC3 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they broke something with the RC2 dependencies.  I just updated an RC2 project to RC3 and it ran fine on Heroku.  Just update the following line in `project/plugins.sbt` to update to RC3:

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0-RC3")
```

Comment: Oh, I thought they are not up to date (sbt 0.11.0), and apparently I was behind (rc2) ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Play 2.0 is now out so you can use `"2.0"` for the version string.